# Active Admin is having problems signing in when after_sign_in_path_for (devise) in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, activeadmin

So I am using Devise for user authentication in my rails app. I have a setup that checks if a user is a member of a league. If he is just a member of 1 league he gets redirected to the user_league page if he has several leagues, he is directed to his/her league index so they can pick what league they want to administer. the 'after_sign_in_path_for' method looks like this

```
def after_sign_in_path_for( resource_or_scope )
    user_leagues = UserLeague.where( :user_id => current_user.id )
    if( user_leagues.count == 1 )
        user_league_url( user_leagues[0].league.id )
    else
        "/users/#{current_user.id}/leagues"
    end
  end
```

I installed the rails admin gem 'Active Admin' which by default uses devise for authentication too. Everytime I try to sign in to Active Admin after installation i get this error:

```
undefined method `admin_user_url' for #<ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:0x007f8be2f3e420>
```

Basically I traced it down to if I remove the function 'after_sign_in_path_for' above and restart my rails server the admin works fine (but i cannot log into my app, the way i want to) and if i put it back in and restart my server, I get the error from the admin page again. Whats am I doing wrong? How can i maintain the login flow of my app and still log into active admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having used ActiveAdmin, I'd guess you are over-riding the way they are using the redirect internally?

You could try wrapping the code in a block of current_user, so your code only fires if it's the user logged in:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if current_user?
    user_leagues = UserLeague.where( :user_id => current_user.id )
    if( user_leagues.count == 1 )
      user_league_url( user_leagues[0].league.id )
    else
      "/users/#{current_user.id}/leagues"
    end
  else
    super
  end
end
```